# Popover presentation on an iPhone using UIPopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, popover

Hello everyone I want to make a popover for iPhone so here is my code where I am geting wrong please suggest I want to create somthing like below pic but mine is covering the whole screen and I dont want to use segue .So basicaly I want if I click on button a resized View controller should popup how can I achieve this please help.I had followed this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQBbJQNEDA4 
[image]

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Popup.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>
{
    Popup * popupController;
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popupPresentationController;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)popupOnClick:(id)sender {

    popupController=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Popup"];
    popupController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popupPresentationController= [popupController popoverPresentationController];
    popupPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popupController.preferredContentSize=CGSizeMake(150, 300);
    popupPresentationController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:popupController animated:YES completion:NULL];


    // in case we don't have a bar button as reference
    popupPresentationController.sourceView = _popupButton;
    popupPresentationController.sourceRect = _popupButton.frame;
}
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller traitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}

@end
```

Comment: Try implementing `adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:traitCollection:` as well.

Comment: @LeoNatan can u please edit the code for me sir.

Comment: No. Read the documentation and implement it in your code.

Comment: @LeoNatan dint work any body else who can give suggestions

Comment: I know for a fact it works, because I have used it on iPhones.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sir I have Tried as I am bit new in iOS Development please modify the Codes if possibe.

Comment: Edited your answer - see if that helps.

Comment: @LeoNatan Sir I have already tried not worked.

Comment: @LeoNatan I have also tried preferedcontentSize but not worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131741/discussion-between-leo-natan-and-harshit-goel).

Comment: @LeoNatan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479764/objective-c-how-to-stop-infinte-loop-while-moving-from-first-vc-to-2nd?noredirect=1#comment70164952_41479764 
please help me in this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
[self presentViewController:popupController animated:YES completion:nil];
popupPresentationController= [popupController popoverPresentationController];
popupPresentationController.delegate = self;
```

That code is in the wrong order. You must set the `delegate` *before* calling `presentViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)