# Objective C how to stop infinte loop while moving from first VC to 2nd

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to build a splash screen so I want the 1st View Controller to move to 2nd ViwController automatically after 3.0 sec I have tried the below method but an infinite loop has started what should i do ,how should I stop on second view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"%p", self);
    NSLog(@"1st Controller");

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        [self loadingNextView];
      });

}

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
- (void)loadingNextView{

    LoginViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
}
//LoginViewController.h
@interface LoginViewController : ViewController

@end
//LoginViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSLog(@"2nd View Controller");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

[image]
see after three seconds how the loop is working .

Comment: The `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` starts the `NSDefaultRunLoopMode`. Why don't you use `dispatch_after` as you commented out?

Comment: @nynohu sir I have tried in both the ways then also the problem is just the same let me update the changes.

Comment: @nynohu yes updated

Comment: If it still call `loadingNextView`, check your `viewWillAppear`, was it called many times?

Comment: @nynohu previously I had used the same thing but this is the first time I am having problem.
and after reaching to second View controller how is it dismissing it back to first View controller ?

Comment: @nynohu nope dint worked I have update the answer again

Comment: How is the infinite loop starting? What's your second viewcontrollers code in viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear?

Comment: @Lefteris just a min sir let me update it

Comment: @Lefteris yes update the answer please check

Comment: You didn't show me the viewDidAppear, but I guess you are not using it. Then your next bet is to look in storyboard. You might have a segue that's being performed when the second view controller appears...

Comment: Just show more little: snippet that you create and display ViewController 1. And it should be better if you show full your ViewController1 and ViewController2. In your current snippet, it seems no problems.

Comment: @nynohu ok sir just give me a min

Comment: @Harshit Goel, `NSLog(@"please stop");` this line code  I do not understand, what mean of your "stop infinte loop" ? you can edit your post more detail.

Comment: It seems other VC1 was created after you back from VC2. Try to put     `NSLog(@"%p", self);` to your VC1 `viewDidLoad`. Check the address printed is same or not?

Comment: @nynohu yes adress is getting changed after evry 3 sec

Comment: @nynohu what happen sir are you there ?

Comment: It means now you create new VC1 each time you back from VC2. Check your project and find where you implement that.

Comment: @nynohu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506009/objective-c-scroll-view-not-working-when-keyboard-appears-and-dissapears?noredirect=1#comment70217752_41506009

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `NSTimer` class. Simply create a timer for 10 seconds when 10 seconds passed timer will trigger the event and in that event you can move to another `controller`. Create a timer like this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:NO];



    - (void)targetMethod:(NSTimer*)timer {
        [self loadingNextView];
    }
```

Comment: What did happen please tell.

Comment: I have tried your way too but i think the problem is somwhere else just have a look at the updated question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506009/objective-c-scroll-view-not-working-when-keyboard-appears-and-dissapears?noredirect=1#comment70217752_41506009

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 repeats:false block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
    [self loadingNextView];
}];
```

So a little advise, you should think about presenting a loginViewController instead pushing it to the NavigationController stack. If you push it, you have to remove the back buttons if you don't want the user to come back to the other ViewController. If you present it you can be sure that the user can't go back to the firstVc without entering his login data.

In the second Vc you then can dismiss the Vc or you can present a new ViewController.

```
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Can you describe what happens? Also infinite loop?

Comment: Sir it moves to second VC after 1 sec but as it moves to 2nd it doesnt stop at 2nd it keeps on dismissing to 1st and then again moves to second, this happens again and again

Comment: So can you post the coding from the second Vc? I tried it, and it works for me. But the method has to be a little diffrent. I edited the Method...

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do, you can add a property to judge if is first come in the vc1:

The result:

[image]

In fitst VC:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL isFirstTime;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _isFirstTime = YES;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
/*  [self performSelector:@selector(loadingNextView)
 withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f]; */

    if (_isFirstTime == NO) {

        return;
    }

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


    [self loadingNextView];
    _isFirstTime = NO;
    });

}
- (void)loadingNextView{

    LoginViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506009/objective-c-scroll-view-not-working-when-keyboard-appears-and-dissapears?noredirect=1#comment70217752_41506009

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve you goal by using this.

```
#import "DrawingViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface DrawingViewController ()

@end

@implementation DrawingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [button removeFromSuperview];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(target:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)target:(NSTimer*)timer {

    SecondViewController* controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer.

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NSLog(@"%p", self);
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            NSLog(@"1st controller");
            [self loadingNextView];
        });

    }


    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    - (void)loadingNextView{

        UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
    }
//LoginViewController.h
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@end
//LoginViewController.m
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"2nd View Controller");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```